# How do I build an oobcoop?

Tags: ooblets

I have a daily task to build an oobcoop but I don't see which build menu I need to use to do this. What do I need to do to build an oobcoop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **shredder machine on the left of Manatwee** (Sprin's furniture shop).

You'll need:

- 3 clothlet
- 15 nurny
- 10 planklet
- 1 oobsidian